# PyInstaller just opens .exe file when debug=True or console=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Here is what is happening:

- 1 - Freezing with debug=True => Generates the .exe file, runs .exe
  without windows console appearing. This is fine, but I don't think leaving debug=True is the proper way to do it.
- 2 - Freezing with console=True => Generates the .exe file, but open the windows console when I open the .exe file clicking on the icon.
  It does not open the windows console when I open the file through the common line.
- 3 - Freezing with console=False and debug=False => Generates the .exe
  file with no errors but when I "open" the .exe file, nothing shows
  up. In the command line, it appears that the command was run and
  nothing happened.

**Any idea for why my .exe file is not running properly when generating it with console=False and debug=False in the executable_3.spec file??**

by .exe file I mean the dist/executable_package_V3/EXE_NAME.exe

I am creating my executable_3.spec file using `pyi-makespec executable_3.py` (I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.7, but also tried with Python 3.6.10 and 3.5.6 and obtained the same results.) and then running `pyinstaller executable_3.spec`

Libraries:

1. pyinstaller=4.0.dev0
2. pyqt5=5.11.3

After a few changes, this is how my executable_3.spec looks like

**My executable_3.spec File:**

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = []

a = Analysis(['src\\executable_3.py'], #executable file path
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Documents\\GitHub\\PROJECT_NAME'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='EXE_NAME', 
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='executable_package_V3')
```

**My executable_3.py file**

```
from GUI import QtCore, QtWidgets, Ui_Dialog #GUI is my UI from Qt Designer
import sys

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use `pyinstaller --windowed app.py`

Comment: I'm not generating the app from my python file, instead, I'm using the .spec file. I already tried pyinstaller --windowed executable_3.spec. I did not help. Also, doesn't console=False in the .spec file produce the same effect?

Comment: I recommend you test which library is causing the problem, I have used that for PyQt5 and it does not generate any problem. Maybe some of the other libraries require the console

Comment: I removed all non-essential libraries and still get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Updating pyinstaller worked for me!

I was in version 4.0 and went to 4.3, looking at the release notes, I saw this pull request that I imagine is what solved in version 4.2: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5446